# How to load a template file from amazon s3 and load it into openpyxl workbook

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, openpyxl, xlsx

I am setting up a server less python application using aws lambda and python for converting csv file to excel.
I want to upload a csv  file and an excel template file into s3 bucket. Then create an excel file using the template file.
I've read the csv data successfully into my application using boto3. Now I want to write the contents into the excel template file.
How can I do that?
I have read somewhere that, we can copy the template file into /tmp in s3 and can be write into that. If so, how is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

With lambda, you can download a file from S3, load it with openpyxl, then do modifications to it and then upload it to S3.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import boto3
import botocore

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def download_file(bucket, key):
    try:
        file = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix = '.xlsx', delete=False)
        s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(key, file.name)
        return file.name
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            return None
        else:
            raise
    else:
        raise

def upload_workbook(workbook, bucket, key):
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
        workbook.save(tmp.name)
        tmp.seek(0)
        s3.meta.client.upload_file(tmp.name, bucket, key)


file = download_file("your-s3-bucket", "your-s3-key")
workbook = load_workbook(file)
# process workbook

upload_workbook(workbook, "your-bucket", "your-key")
```